# Demandoj pri ankaŭ, ne, kaj nur

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

La libro de edukado.net, Poŝamiko (https://edukado.net/poshamiko),  diras ke la vortoj “ankaŭ”, "ne", kaj "nur" efikas la vorton kiun ili rekte antaŭas. Jen ekzemplo:

> Ankaŭ mi faris tiun manĝaĵon/ Ne nur vi

> Mi ankaŭ faris tiun manĝaĵon / Ne nur manĝis

> Mi faris ankaŭ tiun manĝaĵon / Ne nur la alian manĝaĵon

Sed vere mi vidis multajn homojn ne uzi ilin ĉi tiel, ili diras “mi ankaŭ ŝatas” aŭ "mi nur faris" kiam ili celas “ankaŭ/nur mi”. Do mi scivolas cxu:

1. Poŝamiko malpravas
2. Ĝi pravas, sed multaj malobeas aŭ nur ne konas la regulon

Comment: Estas bona ideo serĉi unue tiujn dubojn en gramatikaj libroj. [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/index.html) ekzemple estas kaj bonega kaj rete alirebla (vi verŝajne jam vidis ke oni ĝin multe mencias ĉi tie).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La baza regulo estas ĝusta kaj rekomendinda, sed ĝi ne estas absoluta. [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/index.html) (Plena Manlibro de Esperanta Gramatiko) klarigas tion [jene](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/ceteraj/ankau.html#i-vb4):

> La principo, ke *ankaŭ* staru rekte antaŭ tio, al kio ĝi rilatas, estas
> bona ĝenerala stila rekomendo, sed ĝi ne estas absoluta regulo. En la
> *Fundamento*, ĉe Zamenhof, kaj ankoraŭ hodiaŭ ĉe multaj esperantistoj,
> *ankaŭ* povas stari post la koncernata esprimo. Zamenhof ofte tiel uzis
> *ankaŭ*, kiam ĝi rilatis al persona pronomo, sed ankaŭ en aliaj okazoj

Kaj jen klarigo pri `nur` en [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/ceteraj/nur.html).